# Consuming wierd data from Kafka docker image

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using the confluent kafka docker

```
confluentinc/cp-server:5.4.0
```

I'm producing data from a postgresql.

When I make a consumer and want to retrieve the kafka message, it appears in a format like this

```
codesc�����[�c81e728d9d0.9.4.Finalpostgresqlconektatestdb��ך���KЗ��� public
```

Is there any way that I could retrieve it as Json?

Comment: What command are you using to consume from the topic and in what format is the data? JSON or Avro?

Comment: i'm using `afka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server broker:29092 --topic conekta.public.codes --from-beginning`

How could i know what format is the data? , sorry i'm new to kafka

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what `value.converter` you used  in the Connector.

If you used Avro, you would run `kafka-avro-console-consumer`

If you used any other, you would run `kafka-console-consumer`

Comment: yeah, i used kafka-console-consumer .  

`kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server broker:29092 --topic conekta.public.codes --from-beginning`

The problem is that the message shows like if it was encrypted.

Comment: It is not encrypted. You're seeing UTF-8 encoded binary data (probably Avro). Use the other script I mentioned or fix your connector properties

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Avro to me. You can read it using `kafka-avro-console-consumer`

```sh
kafka-avro-console-consumer \
--bootstrap-server broker:9092 \
--property schema.registry.url=http://schema-registry:8081 \
--topic conekta.public.codes \
--from-beginning
```

Make sure that you set `schema-registry` to the hostname of your Schema Registry.

Ref:

- [Serialisation methods](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/)
- [Converters in Kafka Connect](https://rmoff.dev/crunch19-zero-to-hero-kafka-connect)